# ASP.NET password textbox value set to "Password" automatically

Tags: asp.net, webforms, textbox, passwords

I have a password changer web form in which the admin can just enter a password to be saved in the configuration.

The problem is that when the input text box is left blank, on submit, code behind file receives the password text-box value as "Password" without quotes.

This causes the password to be changed even though it was not intended.

How to fix this?

Comment: Please share your code details so that we can have a look at your code and give some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that there was a jquery watermark plugin that was setting the value for text-box.

Answer (score 1):

There is two possiblities

**1. Make sure you not set value/text of your password box**

**2. Make autocomplete off your password box field by adding `autocomplete="off"` attribute.**